# Is log-general type an intrinsic property of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, compact-manifolds, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb C$.

Let us say that $X$ is of log-general type if for **some** choice of smooth compactification $\bar X$ with normal crossings boundary divisor $D = \bar X \setminus X$, we have that the pair $(\bar X, D)$ is of log-general type. The latter means that $K_{\bar X} + D$ is big.

Is this an intrinsic property? That is, is it independent of the choice of $\bar X$ and $D$?

Also, suppose now that $X$ is only a normal quasi-projective variety. I would like to say $X$ is of log-general type if some desingularization of $X$ is of log-general type. Is this well-defined? That is, is this independent of the chosen desingularization of $X$?

Comment: When you say "boundary divisor", do you require that $D = \tilde{X} \setminus X$? (People often use "boundary" in a much looser sense, but your question seems as though you might mean this more restrictive notion.)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Yes, that's what I meant by boundary.